# Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) shortcut keys are not working for brightness

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, brightness

The shortcut keys for brightness worked great with Lubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa) but do not work with Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish). I use F1 (dimmer) and F2 (brighter).

I am disappointed as my eyes need the ability to modify brightness on the fly.

Any solutions that are not too complicated? For example, I could edit a config file... stuff like that.

Comment: Lubuntu's manual is here (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html) but as F1 & F2 are program specific function keys, they are not directly used (*not without other keys being involved as per manual*).  Different devices can respond differently to other devices though.

Comment: To clarify, I assigned F1 and F2 in the Global Actions Manager (Preferences >> LXQt Settings >> Shortcut Keys) for both versions of Lubuntu. The latest LTS just doesn't work while the former LTS does. A bit of a mystery.

Comment: Do the actions work, but are not triggered when pressing the function keys?

Comment: When I reassign keys to raise volume, lower volume and mute, they all work on both the older and newer versions of Lubuntu. But when I reassign keys for brightness on Jammy Jellyfish, it appears to have received the instructions but does not work when I press the keys---that is, when I am using my PC and want to adjust the brightness with the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Now it seems to be working, with smaller increments than 20.04.5 and less range. But working. I think maybe 22.04.2 depends on how you set brightness with sliders and uses that as a baseline while 20.04.5 gives a full range regardless. Seems to be a difference but I need to study it more, and on different machines.